# How to include the URLs Magento search results in sitemap.xml or generate a new sitemap.xml for this?

Tags: search, seo, sitemaps

I wonder how I can do to generate a new sitemap.xml on Magento whit only the search results, like Wordpress does, generating more urls to send to Google and increasing the ranking search results for users?

Comment: That's wrong. This article is pretty good and explain exactly my question: http://www.goinflow.com/duplicate-content-ecommerce-seo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.... Google hate duplcate content as much as they hate bad links so you can't do that -  http://searchengineland.com/google-warning-against-letting-your-search-results-get-indexed-10709 - you'll get your site an almighty whack if you do - in fact you need to make sure the robots meta tag on your duplicate content which includes filters and search pages is set to "noindex" to cure this problem!

Comment: I agree, but I think this may change according to the SEO strategy of the company. In my case, I decided to release the access of Robots.txt to these pages but Optimized meta title and meta description of each.